# Angular Covalent Datatable row height fit

Tags: angular, datatable

I have a project where use teradata covalent datatable. But I want my row height to be adapted with the length of the colomn 'Name'. How can i change the row heigth to be set to 'fit'?

[image]

```
<td-data-table
      *ngIf="data && filteredData && filteredData?.length > 0"
      #dataTable
      [data]="filteredData"
      [columns]="columns"
      [selectable]="selectable"
      [clickable]="true"
      [multiple]="false"
      [sortable]="true"
      [(ngModel)]="selectedRows"
      [sortOrder]="sortOrder"
      (sortChange)="sort($event)"
      (rowClick)="rowClick($event)"
      [style.height.px]="600">
      <ng-template tdDataTableTemplate="Name" let-value="value" let-row="row" let-column="column">
          <div>
              {{value}}
          </div
      </ng-template>
</td-data-table>
```

In this example it is done right.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/covalent-data-tables-toggle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out this was the solution

```
table[td-data-table] .td-data-table-column-row, table[td-data-table] .td-data-table-row 
{
    height: auto;
}
```